# Deploying the very first project

Tags: laravel, deployment, shared-hosting, namecheap

My project is based on Laravel Jetstream with Livewire. In local machine it works well. The problem occurs when I try to deploy my project on hosting service.

I deployed project on "Namecheap". All looks well but when I open any page except "Welcome Page", I meet with these problem:
GET https://yoursite.loc/build/assets/app-eef14f6e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://yoursite.loc/build/assets/app-246482e5.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
I understand that the site can't find both of them/

I tried to use link href (connect with files from folder Resources) instead of @vite code. Also I tried to move files to Public folder. Also I checked vite.config.js and manifest.json. Support of Namecheap gives me an exact link to file so I see the content of css and js in public/asset/build

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try running `npm run build` on the server ?

Comment: npm run build and other npm commands works only locally, on the server I couldn't use them (Namecheap has a Cpanel, Terminal Bash)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by leaving the 'build' folder in the 'public' folder, and by copying and pasting the 'build' folder again into the main directory of the project. Assuming that you have extracted all the contents of your 'public' folder into the main directory.

Comment: Can you show me how exactly? Because I don't understand. Tried by myself, but no result